# Help me identify a vertical shooter from the 80's, please

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade

Just reaching you guys because I'm completely unable to identify the game, and I haven't seen it in any compilation neither in Mame, etc. The following data are based just in my memories from the 80's. I rembember playing the game around 1985-1986:

- It was a vertical shoot'em up in the old Galaga style (arcade coin-up)
- At the beginning, you had to take off with your spaceship (it was not authomatical, or so do I believe)
- Gameplay was similar to Galaga and some of the enemies were listed in the intro screens as "destroyers" (that looked like crabs!), "saucer" (typical UFO's) or "perseus".

I have to admit that this is just for the sake of curiosity, but I've been trying to identify the game for years and I have been unable to, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it is certainly in MAME but there are too many games to check even within a 1 year period

Comment: Did it scroll with a background or just static screen?

Comment: I'm guessing either Pleiades, Gorf, or Moon Cresta.

Comment: Thanks to everyone so far.  JF: it was an static screen, as far as I can remember. John: many thanks but it is not any of those you mention (checked Youtube). Still searching!

Comment: @JohnGordon: I've played Gorf, and recall that it had 3 or 4 distinct types of levels.  The first one was a straight Space Invaders clone, and the last one was a boss fight in which you could shoot away parts of the enemy spaceship until you hit the one magic pixel that exploded.  Then the cycle repeated, but faster.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [advanced search](https://www.arcade-museum.com/search/) at [Museum of the Game](https://www.arcade-museum.com/), I was able to identify 46 vertical space-themed games released from 1980 to 1987.

Your description resembles 1981's [Satan of Saturn](https://www.arcade-museum.com/game_detail.php?game_id=9435), which is sometimes called [Zarzon](https://snk.fandom.com/wiki/Satan_of_Saturn).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7FxxmHaHCE

Comment: More than that - a search on http://adb.arcadeitalia.net/lista_mame.php (a far better resource than Museum Of The Game IMO) for those years and the genre 'Shooter/Gallery' comes back with over 300. Lots of bootlegs and clones no doubt but still.

Comment: Oooo! I didn't know about that. VERY cool! Editing answer to be less authoritative about the number.

Comment: Thanks, but it was not Satan of Saturn :(. Still searching!

Comment: That's surprising. If it's really a vertical space related shooter, there's only 46 choices from 1980-1987. If it's not Satan of Saturn of Zarzon, there must be some other some detail wrong (Is is really vertical? Is it really an arcade game? Are the years correct?)

I recommend using the linked search to conduct additional research.

Comment: Yup, vertical, but no vertical scrolling at all as far as I can remember; it was more like the typical Space-Invader formula. Years would be 1985-86.

Comment: Oh! Finally I believe I managed to find it, and it seems my memories played some kind of trick with me, because it is no "vertical" shooter, but a semi 3d one.  The  game, finally, with a 99% chance of sucess is the Ambush arcade. Everything matches: the beginning in which you have to take off, the different enemies (saucer, destroyer, etc.) and so on. Only drawback is that it was not a vertical shooter, but I was a 6 year old and I could have been mistaken from the beginning. Thanks a lot for your help! http://adb.arcadeitalia.net/dettaglio_mame.php?game_name=ambushv&search_id=2

Comment: @user26311 you should add an answer, then!